# Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+ <a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a>

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty6oV.png)
Please, what is the solution ?

Comment: just click on install repository

Comment: try to click Install Repository and sync project. It means you do not have it

Answer (score 0):

its just ask for a repository that is not is your system yet. Click on `Install repository and sync` it will install the reqiured repo and sync you projetc again and build will successfull.

Although `com-android-supportappcompat-v725.+` is  not recomended do the exact version or repo.
like `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0`